# I would like a simple query to solve this. We have a simple table with a from and to for merging client data

Tags: sql, db2

I would like a simple query to solve this.

We have a simple table with 4 columns for merging client data. We have to create a loop to transverse the data until the ToClient cannot be found in the FromClient Row. We have one person that has been merged 5 times.

```
FromClient# ToClient#   Userid  Timestamp
1       2       
2       3       
3       4
4       5       
5       6       
7       8
```

What I want is a table created that looks like the following, so it is a simple join for reporting.

```
FromClient# ToClient#
1       6
2       6
3       6
4       6   
5       6
7       8
```

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear from the data you supplied what the rule you are using to transform the data. E.g. should the 1st 3 rows in the output not have 4 as the ToClient?

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in the example. I corrected it. Should be good now.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Try this using Recursive Common Table Expression (RCTE):

```
with 
  mytab (FromClient#, ToClient#) as 
(
values
  (1, 2)
, (2, 3)
, (3, 4)
, (4, 5)
, (5, 6)
, (7, 8)
)
, t (FromClient#, ToClient#) as 
(
select FromClient#, ToClient#
from mytab a
where not exists (select 1 from mytab b where b.FromClient# = a.ToClient#)
  union all
select a.FromClient#, t.ToClient#
from t, mytab a
where a.ToClient# = t.FromClient#
)
select * 
from t
order by FromClient#;
```